# Ho do I send notification payload data to a topic from javascript whenever some data is pushed to my database?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to push a notification to my android whenever some data is pushed to my realtime database.

- My **android** code (this reads the notification data):

  ```
  public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

   @Override
   public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
      FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("electricity bill").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
           String notificationTitle = null, notificationBody = null;

           // Check if message contains a notification payload
           if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
               notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
               notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
           }

           if(Objects.requireNonNull(notificationBody).contains(pf.getText().toString()))
               sendLocalNotification(notificationTitle, notificationBody);
       }
   });
  }

  private void sendLocalNotification(String notificationTitle, String notificationBody) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, record_viewer.class);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
           PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

   Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
   NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
           .setAutoCancel(true)   //Automatically delete the notification
           .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) //Notification icon
           .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
           .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
           .setContentText(notificationBody)
           .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

   notificationManager.notify(1234, notificationBuilder.build());
  }
  }
  ```
- My **web** code (this sends the notification data):

  In my *HTML* page, I have included these libraries:

  ```
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-database-compat.js"></script>
  ```

  And my *javascript*:

  ```
    const firebaseConfig = {
       apiKey: "AIzW&HFSIHF&WUFSJKFVSIUBbsfhs98fhsifj",
       authDomain: "some domain here",
       projectId: "project id",
       storageBucket: "storage bucket",
       messagingSenderId: "123a23283905",
       databaseURL: "https://some url here",
       appId: "some id here"
   };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

     for(var k=1; k<table.rows.length; k++){
          if(table.rows[k].cells.item(10).innerHTML != 0){
               firebase.database().ref("ac/0/").push(
                   {
                        "Current Date":document.getElementsByClassName("curr_date")[k-1].value,
                        "EmpNo":table.rows[k].cells.item(1).innerHTML,
                        "Flag":0,
                        "Prev Date":document.getElementsByClassName("prev_date")[k-1].value,
                        "Total charge":table.rows[k].cells.item(10).innerHTML
                     }
                )
          }
      }

       //How do I send the notification payload to the topic "electricity bill"?
  ```

---

I want to send the `EmpNo` and `Total charge` data through my payload to that topic, how do I proceed? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloud Functions for your use case, specifically [Realtime Database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events). If you're just listening when data is updated in the database, you can use `onCreate()`. You can check the other event handlers [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#set_the_event_handler) so you'll know what fits best to your use case.

Here is a [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/fcm-notifications) on how to send a notification using RTDB trigger for your reference. Just use [sendToTopic()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messaging#messagingsendtotopic) when sending the notification since you're targeting a topic.